# How to activate a registered user by the click of a button in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am learning php and mysql while developing a simple website in the process.

On the site, i want new users to register then get redirected to a welcome page where there is a button to activate their account. They should not be able to login until they click the "Activate" button on the welcome page.

I have been able to create and connect the registration page to a database and also redirect users to welcome page after registering. But how do i activate them when they click 'Activate' button on the welcome page before they can actively login with their username and password.

I do not want to use the email verification process.
How can i fix this?
Below is the code to the welcome page:

```
<?php 
      session_start(); 
      if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must login first";
        header('location: login.php');
      }
      if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: login.php");
      }
    ?>
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome User</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-style">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menuicon">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>   
                        <a href="index.php"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menuicon">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <!-- notification message -->
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
          <div class="error success" >
            <h3>
              <?php 
                echo $_SESSION['success']; 
                unset($_SESSION['success']);
              ?>
            </h3>
          </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <!-- logged in user information -->
        <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h3>
            <p class="small-text"> Click below to activate your username Now!</p>
            <form>
            <script src="https://js.paystack.co/v1/inline.js"></script>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-second" onclick="payWithPaystack()">Activate</button>
            </form>

        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're having?  What is it that needs to be "fixed"?  What is the current result of what you have?

Comment: This is usually done with a GET array taken from what was sent via E-mail. Then, checking to see if the rows exist.

Comment: Right now, a new user can register, get redirected to the welcome page, click the activation button which pops up a payment gatewate. The user have to activate their account with the activation button but right now, even without activating the account, they can still login.

Comment: One of the solution is to put the activated status on the database and when user clicks activate then only give them option to proceed and see other pages .Else always show welcome page whenever they login.

Comment: "even without activating the account, they can still login"  Then the problem seems to be with your login process, not with the welcome page.

Comment: Thanks Funk, i thought same too but don't know how to go about it especially with adding activated status on the database as Rajesh is suggesting.

Comment: Exactly @PatrickQ, how can i update my database such that a user who is not activated can't login? How do i link all of these?

Comment: @FaithAni Welcome. When addressing someone in particular, you need to do as I did here for you. Using the `@the_member_name` with no space between the `@` and username. Some may no longer be present in the question.

Comment: Thanks @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: "how can i update my database such that a user who is not activated can't login"...somewhere you must have some code which handles the login process? You'd just need to change your query so that it checks for "active=1" (or whatever the field is called, and the value held within it is) in addition to checking that the username and password are valid. You didn't show us that bit of the code, so it's not easy to give any more specific instructions than that.

Answer (score 1):

Use active field in database table before clicking button set to 0 by insert query after click set is 1 by update query